# Output a googol copies of a string

Tags: code-golf, string

I am interested in seeing programs which don't ask for any input, print a **googol** copies of some nonempty string, no less, no more, and then stop. A [googol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol) is defined as \$10^{100}\$, i.e., 1 followed by a hundred 0's in decimal.

Example output:

```
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111...
```

or

```
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
...
```

The string can also be entirely composed of white space or special symbols. The only exception to identical copies of a fixed string is if your language decorates the output in some way that can not be prevented, but could be trivially undone in a wrapper script, like prepending a line number to each line. The wrapper script in such cases need not be provided.

You can assume your computer will never run out of time, but other than that, your program must have a reasonable demand of resources. Also, you must respect any restrictions that the programming language of your choice poses, for example, you can not exceed a maximum value allowed for its integer types, and at no point more than 4 GB of memory must be needed.

In other words, the program should *in principle* be testable by running it on your computer. But because of the extent of this number you will be expected to **prove** that the number of copies of the string it outputs is exactly 10^100 and that the program stops afterwards. Stopping can be exiting or halting or even terminating due to an error, but if so, the error must not produce any output that could not easily be separated from the program's output.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf),  so the solution with the fewest bytes wins.

### Example solution (C, ungolfed, 3768 bytes)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a00, a01, a02, a03, ..., a99;
  for(a00 = 0; a00 < 10; a00++)
  for(a01 = 0; a01 < 10; a01++)
  for(a02 = 0; a02 < 10; a02++)
  for(a03 = 0; a03 < 10; a03++)
  ...
  for(a99 = 0; a99 < 10; a99++)
    puts("1");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: First question here. Improvements, style/tag corrections, comments etc. welcome. Have fun!

Comment: Consider [the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140) first next time.

Comment: @cat Sorry, I don't understand what that link is about. CW is community wiki, right? How is that related?

Comment: When you post a new question, [you are asked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to first post it in [the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges).

Comment: @flawr Should I delete this and repost there?

Comment: @flawr I'm afraid someone may already be working on it. I'm sorry, somehow the line slipped my attention :-(

Comment: Next, somebody should create a challenge needing to output a ---Google Plex---googleplex copies of a string

Comment: @KritixiLithos It was toying with that idea but I could not quickly come up with a sample solution. Feel free to make a sequel :-)

Comment: Does it have to be separate print statements? Or can we do something like `print's'*(10**100)`?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk You did not specify language but if this generically means creating a string 10^100 characters long and then printing it then that's what the "realistic computer" and memory restriction are meant to be against. The 4 GB is just an arbitrary number but this would require something far beyond all SI prefixes.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't judge whether that happens in the programs written in languages I don't understand, but I hope that's what the community will detect. This happened in some of the answers, I'm not going to cite because the respective authors decided to hide their comment discussion.

Comment: But if your language uses lazy stream creation and printing, sure, go for it. Or if this means "repeat `print's'` 10^100 times".

Comment: @closevoter Are you sure this is too broad? Common sense automatically narrows this down from "print a nonempty string 10^100 times" to "print a character 10^100 times".

Comment: You can separate error output with `2>nul` or `2>/dev/null`, depending on your OS :)

Comment: @KritixiLithos *Googolplex

Comment: @Oliver I can't stop thinking about Google that it has entered my subconsciousness :D

Comment: [TIL Googol-1 in Roman numerals](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=googol-1+in+Roman&lk=2)

Comment: "at no point no more than 4 GB of memory must be needed" means that more than 4GB of memory must be needed at all times

Comment: Can I write `main=putStr$cycle"x"`, which prints `s` a googol times, where `s` is the infinite string with all characters `x`?

Comment: @wchargin Nice try :-) But your program would print just a single copy of `s`. The ordinal ω . 10^100 that you would need there is clearly distinctive from ω.

Comment: Are we allowed to use the system time? Something like making one output a second, and then terminating the program when the time 1 googol seconds after the current system time is reached.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
³Ȯ*¡
```

This is a niladic link (function w/o arguments) that prints **10<sup>200</sup>** copies of the string **100**, meaning that it prints **10<sup>100</sup>** copies of the string that consists of **10<sup>100</sup>** copies of the string **100**.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrPIrirCoQrCoiAgICAgIOG5m-KAnENhbGxzIHRoZSBuaWxhZGljIGxpbmsu4oCd4bmb4oCc&input=)

Note that the online interpreter cuts the output at 100 KB for practical reasons. The code also works as a full program, but due to implicit output, that program prints one copy too many.

#### How it works

```
³Ȯ*¡  Niladic link. No arguments.

³     Set the left argument and initial return value to 100.
 Ȯ    Print the current return value.
  *   Compute 100 ** 100 = 1e200.
   ¡  Call Ȯ 1e200 times.
```

Comment: Well... Wow... Printing `10^100` copies of the original output (`10^100` copies of a string) is taking it a *little* far, even for two whole bytes. Have you submitted this to the "score is output / program-length, highest wins" challenge yet?

Comment: Not sure which challenge you're referring to (we had a few of this type), but **3e200** probably isn't competitive anyway.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 If you can express your number in standard notation it's probably waaay too small.

Comment: Truly fascinating language and answer. I think no one is going to beat 4 bytes!! :-D Thanks for all your active participation in spotting programs which would not pass the rules, too!

Comment: Does this actually work?  I would think it would fall over on 100 ** 100

Comment: @LorenPechtel I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by *fall over*?

Comment: "Fall over" = fail/crash

Comment: @LorenPechtel I see no reasons why it would. This is a simple *for* loop, so memory holds nothing more than the integer **100**, a counter, the 665-bit limit, and the interpreter itself. Of course it will never *finish* printing the **3e200** characters it is supposed to, but that's something all valid answers to this challenge have in common...

Comment: Unless you have unlimited length integers your 100 ** 100 is going to be a problem.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Jelly is implemented in Python, which handles 665-bit integers with ease.

Comment: @LorenPechtel If the upper bound was a problem, the program would fail before entering the `for` loop, as you observed. But one can easily check that this does not happen in the online evaluator.

Comment: I think this actually prints **10²⁰⁰+1** copies of `100`. I have tested it with `2Ȯ*¡`, and, while it should have printed 2²=4 `2`s, it printed five instead (`22222` instead of `2222`), because `Ȯ` returns z. Something similar would happen to `100` too, given enough time and memory etc. I think that makes it invalid. However, I have found a simple 6-byte solution that is valid: `³Ȯ*¡ṛ“`. `ṛ“` solves the exact problem I've described, it replaces the value returned by `Ȯ` (`100`) by the empty string (`[]`).

Comment: @EriktjeOutgolfer This is a *function* submission. As I said in my answer, *the code also works as a full program, but due to implicit output, that program prints one copy too many.*.

Comment: @Dennis You typo'd my name, so I didn't see your reply. What I think though is that OP asked for a program. They mention being interested in programs, but no reference to functions.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Whoops, sorry for the botched ping. On PPCG, [program means full program or function](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6912/12012).

Comment: @Dennis TBH I haven't seen that post in the past. Even though it's not the most popular answer, it is the most popular answer which defines "program". I couldn't have imagined such a thing...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer it's just a default. questions are welcome to specify "no functions", but it has to be made explicit.

Comment: I don't think I could beat this in any of the languages I know.

Comment: @ckjbgames the languages designed for golfing generally aren't beatable by normal languages. that doesn't mean those normal languages aren't worth using. it's common here to encourage at least one answer in each language. we usually don't compare python answers to pyth answers, just to each other.

Answer (score 62):

## Fuzzy Octo Guacamole, <s>13</s> <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
9+ddpp![g]
```

Explanation:

```
9+ddpp![g]
9+           # push 9 and increment, giving 10
  dd         # duplicate, twice. now you have [10,10,10]
    pp       # raise a 10 to the 10th power, then raise that to the 10th again. That ends up being 10^100.
      ![ ]   # for loop, `!` sets the counter to the top of stack
        g    # prints an ASCII art goat.
```

Sample of the goat printed:

```
                  ___.
                 //  \\
                ((   ""
                 \\__,
                /6 (%)\,
               (__/:";,;\--____----_
                ;; :";,:";`;,";,;";`,`_
                  ;:,;;";";,;":,";";,-Y\
                   ;,;,;";";,;":;";"; Z/
                   / ;,";";,;";,;";;"
                  / / |";/~~~~~\";;"
                 ( K  | |      || |
                  \_\ | |      || |
                   \Z | |      || |
                      L_|      LL_|
                      LW/      LLW/
```

Comment: It took me a while to understand the head of the goat. It's not easily recognizable.

Comment: The gaot gave me the ASCII art, ask him about it.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. +1.

Comment: @djechlin Downgoat asked me to add a builtin for printing a goat. I obliged.

Answer (score 23):

## Python,  28 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan!*

**Python 2:**

```py
i=10**100
while i:print;i-=1
```

**Python 3 (30 bytes):**

```py
i=10**100
while i:print();i-=1
```

Comment: `i=10**100` newline `while i:print();i-=1` saves a byte. Save two more by using Python 2 with `while i:print;i-=1`

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks for the -1 byte. As for the Python 2 solution, I'll leave that for you to post :)

Comment: Nice first answer! :)

Comment: Can Python actually store 10 to the 100 in an integer?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez yep, there's no upper limit on int size in python :)

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen It doesn't need 4GB... According to wikipedia, [you need 333 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol#Properties). The python function `sys.getsizeof()` tells me that it's 58 bytes. Either way, that's nowhere near the limit this challenge specifies, and it runs fine on my laptop.

Comment: I'm not well versed in dynamically typed languages, but could you save two bytes by going like so: `while i<10**100:print();i+=1` ?

Comment: @tuskiomi well, I'd still need to define `i=0` at the top, which would end up costing 2 more bytes.

Comment: i cannot be defined implicitly as null?

Comment: @tuskiomi nope, `i` has to have a value before it can be used

Comment: You could save several bytes by not assigning a variable and fitting it all on one line, like this: `while 10**100:print();i-=1`

Comment: @ckjbgames No I couldn't, because `while 10**100` will always evaluate to true, and `i-=1` would throw a `NameError` as we haven't defined `i`.

Comment: @FlipTack Also didn't consider that. I put it through a byte counter and found the same. I don't know if it can be golfed any more than the Python 2 version.

Answer (score 18):

### Haskell, 28 bytes

```
main=putStr$[1..10^100]>>"1"
```

Concatenates 10^100 copies of the string `"1"` and prints it.

Comment: Is the string concatenation done before the printing starts? If so I would think this breaks the rule about "no more than 4 GB of memory"...

Comment: @daniero: thanks to Haskell's laziness printing starts immediately. On my computer the program needs less than 2MB memory (including the run time system RTS).

Comment: Is `s=[1..10^100]>>"1"` an allowed answer format?

Comment: Infinite integers?  Otherwise it falls over on 10^100

Comment: @immibis: the challenge says "print", which usually means "print to stdout". `s` from your example doesn't print - or if you use the REPL surrounds the `1` with `"`. I guess just `putStr$[1..10^100]>>"1"` without the `main=` would be fine, but I wanted to submit a full program.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: not "infinite", but arbitrary large. Type `10^100` in the online repl at the home page of [www.haskell.org](http://www.haskellorg) and it happily prints the result.

Answer (score 17):

## Brainfuck, <del>480</del> <del>188</del> <del>114</del> <del>106</del> 98 bytes

Just because it needs to be done.

Assumes 8-bit cells with wrapping. Prints 250<sup>255</sup> NUL bytes, which is 10<sup>100</sup> times 10<sup>155</sup> times 25<sup>255</sup> NUL bytes.

```
>>>>>>-[[->>>+<<<]------>>>-]<<<[<<<]+[+[>>>]<<<->+[<[+>-]>[-<<<<->+>>------>>]<<<<]>>-[<<<].>>>-]
```

Explanation:

`>>>>>>` is needed to leave a bit of working space.

`-` produces 255.

`[[->>>+<<<]------>>>-]` turns this into 255 copies of the value 250, giving a tape that looks like:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 250 0 0 250 0 0 ... 250 0 0 [0]
```

`<<<[<<<]+` moves the data pointer back and finishes up the initial data:

```
0 0 0 [1] 0 0 250 0 0 250 0 0 ...
```

Then comes the loop: `[+...-]` initially sets the 1 to a 2, which gets set back to 1 at the end of the loop. The loop terminates when the loop body already set 2 to 1.

Now, the numbers 2 250 250 250 ... 250 represent a counter, in base 250, with each number one greater than the digit it represents.

- `[>>>]<<<` moves all the way to the right. Since each digit is represented by a non-zero number, this is trivial.
- `->+[<[+>-]>[-<<<<->+>>------>>]<<<<]>>-` decreases the counter by 1. Starting with the last digit: the digit gets decremented. If it remains positive, we're done. If it turns to zero, set it to 250, and continue with the digit before.
- `[<<<].>>>` moves the pointer back before the left-most digit, and this is a nice moment to print a NUL byte. Then re-position to exactly the left-most digit, to see if we're done.

To verify correctness, change the initial `-` to `+` to print 250<sup>1</sup> NUL bytes, `++` for 250<sup>2</sup>, etc.

Answer (score 16):

## C, 51 bytes

Function `g()` calls recursive function `f()` to depth 99.

Excludes unnecessary newline added between `f()` and `g()` for clarity.

```
f(n,i){for(i=10;i--;)n?f(n-1):puts("");}
g(){f(99);}

//call like this
main(){g();}
```

Prints 1E100 newlines.

Declaration of `i` as second parameter of `f()` not guaranteed to work in all versions of C. Tested on my own machine (GCC on CygWin) and on ideone.com (I believe they also run GCC), but not up to f(99) for obvious reasons!

Comment: Does that comply with the 4 GiB memory limit?

Comment: @Dennis It should do, it only stores a depth 99 recursion of f,n and i on the  stack, getting around the fact that C can´t handle a 100 digit number decimal number. I would estimate a max of about 20 bytes for each instance of `f()` so about 1980 bytes. The `puts` dumps the newlines to the API and the API should output and flush the buffer as necessary.

Comment: Tested it locally and memory usage doesn't even surpass 1 MiB.

Comment: *Declaration of i as second parameter of f() not guaranteed to work in all versions of C.*: It could break with a stack-args calling convention where the callee pops args from the stack (or if `f` writes to stack space that the caller wasn't expecting it to).  clang does warn about "too few arguments in call to 'f'", in `-std=c89` and `-std=c99`, so the definition does act as a declaration with a specific number of args.  But I forget; I think that might mean the compiler knows the function expects 2 args, and will always leave space for a 2nd arg.

Comment: Of course the C standard doesn't say anything about call stacks, but more generally doesn't the visibility of the `f(n,i)` definition imply that the `f(99)` call must do whatever is necessary?  (Sorry I'm lazy and didn't try to look this up in the standard myself, but in the asm output of `clang3.8 -std=c89 -m32 -O2`, `g()` does initialize two 4B spaces on the stack.  That's on Linux with a caller-pops calling convention with no register args, but where the called function is allowed to overwrite its args (even though compilers don't make code that does that))

Comment: I used this as a starting point for [an x86-64 machine-code version of this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97975/output-a-googol-copies-of-a-string/98105#98105), coming in at 30 bytes when using a putchar('\n') libc function call for printing.

Comment: Strictly speaking, "write a program" means you don't really need `g` but you do need `main`, don't you?

Comment: @FelixDombek the community decided a while back that "program" means you can write a program or function unless "full program" is explicitly specified. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6912/15599 . Therefore my submission comprises `g` and its helper function `f`. `main` would be longer. There are a few other function submissions here, if you look through.

Answer (score 15):

### Commodore VIC 20 machine code (40 bytes)

... here shown as hexadecimal:

```
1040   A9[64]A2 00 9D 68 10 E8  E0[32]D0 F8 A9 00 9D 68
1050   10 A9[31]20 D2 FF A2 00  A9[64]DE 68 10 30 08 D0
1060   F0 9D 68 10 E8 D0 F3 60
```

(Started using: `SYS 4160`)

**Meaning of the bytes in brackets**

- 0x64 (occurs twice) is the base (100); (values from 2 to 127 should work)
- 0x32 is the exponent (50) (any non-zero value (1-255) should work)
- Note that 100^50 = 10^100; running the program 100^50 times is more RAM efficient than doing it 10^100 times
- 0x31 is the ASCII character to be printed

> and at no point no more than 4 **G**B of memory must be needed.

Is this a typing mistake?

We have the year 1981.

A typical home computer has 1 to 16 **K**B of RAM! And you will hardly find professional models that have 1 **M**B or more.

(Ok. Just a joke.)

> In other words, the program should in principle be testable by running it on your computer. But because of the extent of this number you will be expected to prove that the number of copies of the string it outputs is exactly 10^100 and that the program stops afterwards.

The program has been tested with other bases and exponents. I have no doubt it will also work with 100 and 50.

At least it does not crash with these numbers (but does not terminate in measurable time either).

The memory size is sufficient for an exponent of 50 and 100 is less than 127 so a base of 100 should not be a problem.

**The the basic idea**

There is a 50-digit counter that counts in the 100-system. Bytes 0x01-0x64 represent the digits 0-99. The first byte in the counter is the lowest digit. The last byte in the counter (highest digit) is followed by a byte with the value 0x00.

The counter has the initial value 100^50.

An outer loop is writing a byte to the "current channel" ("standard output" on modern systems; typically the screen) and then decrements the counter.

Decrementing is done by an inner loop: It decrements a digit and in the case of an underflow from 1 to 99 it advances to the next digit. If the byte 0x00 at the end of the counter is decremented the program stops.

**The assembly code is**

```
    ; Some constants
    base=10
    exponent=100
    character=0x32

    ; Initialize the content of the counter to 100^50
    ; (Fill the first 50 bytes with the value 100)
    lda  #base
    ldx  #0
initLoop:
    sta  counter,x
    inx
    cpx  #exponent
    bne  initLoop
    ; (The terminating 0 at the end of the counter)
    lda  #0
    sta  counter,x

    ; Now do the actual job
outerLoop:
    ; Output a character
    lda  #character
    jsr  (0xFFD2)
    ; Prepare for the inner loop
    ldx  #0
    lda  #base
innerLoop:
    ; Decrement one digit
    dec  counter,x
    ; Result is negative -> must have been the terminating
    ; NUL byte -> Exit
    bmi  progEnd
    ; Result is not zero -> Print the next byte
    bne  outerLoop
    ; Result is zero -> Was 0x01 before -> As 0x01 represents
    ; digit 0 this is an underflow -> set the digit to
    ; "exponent" (100) again (which represents digit 99)
    sta  counter,x
    ; Go to the next digit and...
    inx
    ; ... repeat the inner loop (decrement next digit)
    ; (Note that this conditional branch is ALWAYS taken)
    bne  innerLoop

progEnd:
    rts

counter:
    ; The memory used by the counter is here...
```

**EDIT**

The program runs on Commodore C64, too!

Comment: I borrowed @LevelRiverSt's recursion idea for my [x86-64 machine-code implementation](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97975/output-a-googol-copies-of-a-string/98105#98105), coming in at 30B (using putchar from libc for printing).  I considered an extended-precision loop counter, and it would work in x86, too.  (And can similarly be pretty cheaply initialized).  Maybe I'll try it sometime...

Comment: LOL wow, I .... <golf clap> ... I haven't seen 6502 assembly in ... well, a long time.

Answer (score 12):

## Node, 89 bytes

```
for(i="0".repeat(100)+1;+i;i=i.replace(/0*./,x=>"9".repeat(x.length-1)+~-x))console.log()
```

Outputs 10<sup>100</sup> newlines. (Theoretically, that is; test by replacing `100` with `1` to output 10<sup>1</sup> newlines instead.)

This works by setting `i` to the string

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

(100 zeroes and a 1; a googol reversed), then repeatedly "subtracting 1" with a regex replace and outputting a newline until the string is all zeroes.

A port of the C++ answer would be 49 bytes:

```
(f=n=>{for(i=10;i--;)n?f(n-1):console.log()})(99)
```

Comment: This is genius! Either that or you're an expert at Retina, which doesn't necessarily rule out "genius"...

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
Tn°F1?
```

**Explanation**

```
Tn°    # push 10^100
   F   # 10^100 times do
    1? # print 1
```

Comment: How about the data types? Do they allow integers up to 10^100?

Comment: @MartinRosenau: Fortunately 05AB1E uses python 3 integers which doesn't have a limit.

Comment: @Emigna every integer has its limit. 2^1e9 is a lot, but I'm not sure python can get that high. 1e100 should be well within the range of any big integer, though.

Comment: @JanDvorak: According to the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers) *there is no longer a limit to the value of integers*.

Comment: I'm curious if Python can actually handle 4GiB numbers like they say...

Comment: @JanDvorak: Indeed. I have used some pretty big numbers without issues (not that big though). We only need to handle 1e100 here though and python can definitely handle that :)

Comment: @JanDvorak The maximum size of Python integers is solely dependent on the amount of available memory.

Comment: I have gotten to the limit before while trying to obfuscate a long number. The machine I was using was able to handle numbers bigger than 10^3000 before an integer overflow.

Answer (score 7):

## [Slashalash](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Slashalash), 36 ASCII characters (4 distinct)

```
/t./.ttttt//.t/t\..........//t//t...
```

Outputs the `.` character 3*10^125 times, meaning that it outputs the string consisting of 3*10^25 repetitions of the `.` character, 10^100 times.

Explanation:

1. `/t./.ttttt/`: Replace `t.` with `.ttttt` throughout the rest of the program, repeating until no instances of `t.` remain. This replaces `t...` with `...` followed by 125 `t`s.
2. `/.t/t\........../`: Replace `.t` with `t..........` throughout the rest of the program, repeating until no instances of `.t` remain. This takes the `...` followed by 125 `t`s, and turns it into 125 `t`s followed by 10^125 occurrences of `...`.
3. `/t//`: Remove all remaining `t`s.
4. `t...`: This gets replaced with 3*10^125 `.`s. Output them.

Now, outputting 10^100 repetitions of 3*10^25 repetitions of something kind of feels like cheating. This program outputs the `.` character exactly 10^100 times, using 45 ASCII characters:

```
/T/tttttttttt//.t/t..........//t//.TTTTTTTTTT
```

Explanation of this one:

1. `/T/tttttttttt/`: Replace `T` with `tttttttttt` throughout the rest of the program. This replaces `TTTTTTTTTT` with 100 repetitions of `t`.
2. `/.t/t........../`: Replace `.t` with `t..........` throughout the rest of the program. This takes the `.` followed by 100 `t`s, and turns it into 100 `t`s followed by 10^100 `.`s.
3. `/t//`: Remove all remaining `t`s.
4. `.TTTTTTTTTT`: This gets replaced with 10^100 `.`s. Output them.

Finally, here's a compromise program, which outputs the `.` character 2*10^100 times, using 40 characters:

```
/t./.tttttttttt//.t/t\..........//t//t..
```

Comment: Does it at some moment store `".."*10*100` overflowing memory?

Comment: @l4m2 Yep, it does.

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby, 20 bytes

```
(10**100).times{p 1}
```

Prints 1 followed by a newline 1E100 times.

`1E100` does not work as it evaluates to a float, not an arbitrary precision integer.

Comment: Can you remove the parentheses?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 No. methods take priority over operators, so it would be interpreted as `10**(100.times{p 1})`

Comment: For those curious, `1E100.to_i` evaluated to 10000000000000000159028911097599180468360808563945281389781327557747838772170381060813469985856815104 on my computer.

Answer (score 6):

### Befunge 93, 33 bytes

```
1>01g0`#@!# _01v
d^.1 **52p10-1g<
```

Unfortunately, Befunge does not have a power function, so almost all of that code is my implementation of a power function. I'm still working on this.

Explanation:

```
1 > 01g 0` #@!# _ 01g 1- 01p 25** 1. v
d ^                                  <
```

`1`: Start off with `1` in the top left so that when we multiply, we don't get `0` every time.

`01g`: get the character at position (0, 1), which is `d`, whose ASCII code is 100.

`` 0` ``: see if the value stored in (0, 1) is greater than 0; this value will change.

`#@!# _`: Logical not `!` to the value we get from the last step (0 or 1), so that if it was 1, now we have 0, and we  Note that `#` means that you skip the next character in the code.

`01g 1- 01p`: Take the value stored in (0, 1) again, subtract 1 from it, and store this new value at (0, 1)

`25**`: multiply the top value of the stack by 10

`1.`: print `1` every time this loops

`1` is printed (in theory) googol times, but that quickly runs off of the page that I tested this on.

You can run Befunge 93 code [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html). For some reason, the top value of the stack is `1.0000000000000006e+100` when it should be `1.0e+100`. I don't know where that `6` came from, but I don't think it should be there and that it may be some rounding error or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

## [ABCR](https://github.com/Steven-Hewitt/ABCR), 56 bytes

```
++++++++++AAAAAAAAAA7a*A!(x4bBBBBBBBBBB7b+B@(xa(Ax5b(Box
```

Turing tarpits are fun, especially when they don't have easy multiplication or exponents.  On the other hand, I only needed to use two of the three queues!

Explanation:

```
++++++++++                                             Set register to 10
          AAAAAAAAAA                                   Queue 10 to queue A 10 times
                    7a*A!(x                            Sum up all of queue A by:
                    7     x                             While the register is truthy:
                     a*                                 Dequeue two elements of A, sum them...
                       A                                ...and queue the result back to A.
                        !(                              If there's only one element left,
                                                        i.e. !(A.len - 1),
                                                        break from the loop.  A now has 100, our exponent.
                            
                             4                        While A's front is truthy:
                              bBBBBBBBBBB              Clone the front of B 10 (our base) times.  (The first iteration fills it up with ten 1s)
                                         7b+B@(x       Sum up all of queue B like we did with A
                                                a(A    Decrement a (so that the loop actually ends. Runs 101 times like it should) x   

                                                       B now contains 10^100 only.

                                                   5b(B x   10^100 times:
                                                       o     print the front of queue A (0)
```

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, <s>574</s> 242 bytes

```
@echo off
set t=for /l %%a in (2,1,33554432)do call:
set f=for /l %%a in (2,1,9765625)do call:
%t%a
:a
%t%b
:b
%t%c
:c
%t%d
:d
%f%e
:e
%f%f
:f
%f%g
:g
%f%h
:h
%f%i
:i
%f%j
:j
%f%k
:k
%f%l
:l
%f%m
:m
%f%n
:n
echo
```

Each loop falls through therefore executing an additional iteration. Loops are limited to ~2³² due to the 32-bit integer limit. The first four loops each count 2²⁵ for a total of 2¹⁰⁰ while the remaining ten loops each count 5¹⁰ for a total of 5¹⁰⁰.

Edit: Saved an unimaginable 58% thanks to @ConorO'Brien.

Comment: [I golfed it down considerably.](http://pastebin.com/fk1QrVdy)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Wait, you can do that? I never knew!

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 44 bytes

```
for($i=bcpow(10,1e2);$i=bcsub($i,print 1););
```

This snippet will output `1` googol times. It will not run out of memory, but it is terribly slow. I'm using BCMath to be able to handle long integers.

A bit better performing, but not as small (74 bytes):

```
for($m=bcpow(10,100);$m;$m=bcsub($m,$a))echo str_repeat(a,$a=min(4e9,$m));
```

Will output the letter `a` googol times. It will consume almost 4GB of memory, outputting about 4e9 characters at a time.

Comment: if just an 'a' takes almost 4GB, what would 'aaa' do? It will take more code, but with ob_flush(); you might go a lot further

Comment: Uhm, it's not one `a`, it's a string of 4*10^9 `a`s. There no way not go over the 4GB if you're going to put 3 times as many `a`s in there. Ob_flush has nothing to do with it, the point of the second example is to output large strings at once instead of outputting small amounts of characters each time, which results in the program running quite a bit faster, at the cost of more memory usage.

Comment: As far as I know ">=" is not able to handle big integers, you should use bccomp

Comment: You are correct, it doesn't give the correct results when comparing strings. I will fix it in a minute.

Comment: Edit with a somewhat different but working solution :)

Answer (score 4):

## x86-64 machine code function, 30 bytes.

Uses the same recursion logic as [the C answer by @Level River St](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97975/output-a-googol-copies-of-a-string/97993#97993).  (Max recursion depth = 100)

Uses the `puts(3)` function from libc, which normal executables are linked against anyway.  It's callable using the x86-64 System V ABI, i.e. from C on Linux or OS X, and doesn't clobber any registers it's not supposed to.

---

`objdump -drwC -Mintel` output, commented with explanation

```
0000000000400340 <g>:  ## wrapper function
  400340:       6a 64                   push   0x64
  400342:       5f                      pop    rdi       ; mov edi, 100  in 3 bytes instead of 5
  ; tailcall f by falling into it.

0000000000400343 <f>:  ## the recursive function
  400343:       ff cf                   dec    edi
  400345:       97                      xchg   edi,eax
  400346:       6a 0a                   push   0xa
  400348:       5f                      pop    rdi       ; mov edi, 10
  400349:       0f 8c d1 ff ff ff       jl     400320 <putchar>   # conditional tailcall
; if we don't tailcall, then eax=--n = arg for next recursion depth, and edi = 10 = '\n'

  40034f:       89 f9                   mov    ecx,edi   ; loop count = the ASCII code for newline; saves us one byte


0000000000400351 <f.loop>:
  400351:       50                      push   rax       ; save local state
  400352:       51                      push   rcx
  400353:       97                      xchg   edi,eax   ; arg goes in rdi
  400354:       e8 ea ff ff ff          call   400343 <f>
  400359:       59                      pop    rcx       ; and restore it after recursing
  40035a:       58                      pop    rax
  40035b:       e2 f4                   loop   400351 <f.loop>
  40035d:       c3                      ret    
# the function ends here

000000000040035e <_start>:
```

**`0x040035e - 0x0400340 = 30 bytes`**

```
# not counted: a caller that passes argc-1 to f() instead of calling g
000000000040035e <_start>:
  40035e:       8b 3c 24                mov    edi,DWORD PTR [rsp]
  400361:       ff cf                   dec    edi
  400363:       e8 db ff ff ff          call   400343 <f>
  400368:       e8 c3 ff ff ff          call   400330 <exit@plt>    # flush I/O buffers, which the _exit system call (eax=60) doesn't do.
```

[Built with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649) `yasm -felf64 -Worphan-labels -gdwarf2 golf-googol.asm &&
 gcc -nostartfiles -o golf-googol golf-googol.o`.  I can post the original NASM source, but that seemed like clutter since the asm instructions are right there in the disassembly.

`putchar@plt` is less than 128 bytes away from the `jl`, so I could have used a 2-byte short jump instead of a 6-byte near jump, but that's only true in a tiny executable, not as part of a larger program.  So I don't think I can justify not counting the size of libc's puts implementation if I also take advantage of a short jcc encoding to reach it.

**Each level of recursion uses 24B of stack space** (2 pushes and the return address pushed by CALL).  Every other depth will call `putchar` with the stack only aligned by 8, not 16, so this does violate the ABI.  A stdio implementation that used aligned stores to spill xmm registers to the stack would fault.  But glibc's `putchar` doesn't do that, writing to a pipe with full buffering or writing to a terminal with line buffering.  Tested on Ubuntu 15.10.  This could be fixed with a dummy push/pop in the `.loop`, to offset the stack by another 8 before the recursive call.

---

Proof that it prints the right number of newlines:

```
   # with a version that uses argc-1  (i.e. the shell's $i)  instead of a fixed 100
$ for i in {0..8}; do echo -n "$i: "; ./golf-googol $(seq $i) |wc -c; done
0: 1
1: 10
2: 100
3: 1000
4: 10000
5: 100000
6: 1000000
7: 10000000
8: 100000000
... output = 10^n newlines every time.
```

---

My first version of this was 43B, and used `puts()` on a buffer of 9 newlines (and a terminating 0 byte), so puts would append the 10th.  That recursion base-case was even closer to the C inspiration.

Factoring 10^100 a different way could maybe have shortened the buffer, maybe down to 4 newlines, saving 5 bytes, but using putchar is better by far.  It only needs an integer arg, not a pointer, and no buffer at all.  The C standard allows implementations where it's a macro for `putc(val, stdout)`, but in glibc it exists as a real function that you can call from asm.

Printing only one newline per call instead of 10 just means we need to increase the recursion max depth by 1, to get another factor of 10 newlines.  Since 99 and 100 can both be represented by a sign-extended 8-bit immediate, `push 100` is still only 2 bytes.

Even better, having `10` in a register works as both a newline and a loop counter, saving a byte.

**Ideas for saving bytes**

A 32-bit version could save a byte for the `dec edi`, but the stack-args calling convention (for library functions like putchar) makes tail-call work less easily, and would probably require more bytes in more places.  I could use a register-arg convention for the private `f()`, only called by `g()`, but then I couldn't tail-call putchar (because f() and putchar() would take a different number of stack-args).

It would be possible to have f() preserve the caller's state, instead of doing the save/restore in the caller.  That probably sucks, though, because it would probably need to get separately in each side of the branch, and isn't compatible with tailcalling.  I tried it but didn't find any savings.

Keeping a loop counter on the stack (instead of push/popping rcx in the loop) didn't help either.  It was 1B worse with the version that used puts, and probably even more of a loss with this version that sets up rcx more cheaply.

Comment: Hooray for assembly answers! :)

Answer (score 4):

## Turing machine simulator, 1082 bytes

```
0 * 6 r 1
1 * E r 2
2 * C r 3
3 * 1 r 4
4 * B r 5
5 * C r 6
6 * F r 7
7 * 4 r 8
8 * 6 r 9
9 * 8 r A
A * 8 r B
B * 3 r C
C * 0 r D
D * 9 r E
E * G r F
F * H r G
G * 8 r H
H * 0 r I
I * 6 r J
J * H r K
K * 9 r L
L * 3 r M
M * 2 r N
N * A r O
O * D r P
P * C r Q
Q * C r R
R * 4 r S
S * 4 r T
T * E r U
U * E r V
V * G r W
W * 6 r X
X * D r Y
Y * E r Z
Z * 0 r a
a * F r b
b * E r c
c * 9 r d
d * F r e
e * A r f
f * H r g
g * D r h
h * E r i
i * 6 r j
j * 6 r k
k * D r l
l * G r m
m * H r n
n * 1 r o
o * 0 r p
p * 8 r q
q * C r r
r * 9 r s
s * G r t
t * 3 r u
u * 6 r v
v * 2 r w
w * 3 r x
x * E r y
y * 0 r z
z * 4 r +
+ * 5 r /
/ * A r =
= * 0 r -
- * H r \
\ * 7 r !
! * A r @
@ * 9 r #
# * 5 r $
$ * A r %
% * B r ^
^ * 5 r &
& * 9 r ?
? * 4 r (
( * C r )
) * E r `
` * 9 r ~
~ * 9 r _
_ * A * .
. 0 I l *
. 1 0 r <
. 2 1 r <
. 3 2 r <
. 4 3 r <
. 5 4 r <
. 6 5 r <
. 7 6 r <
. 8 7 r <
. 9 8 r <
. A 9 r <
. B A r <
. C B r <
. D C r <
. E D r <
. F E r <
. G F r <
. H G r <
. I H r <
. _ * r ]
< _ * r >
< * * r *
> _ = l [
> * * r *
[ _ * l .
[ * * l *
] _ * * halt
] * _ r *
```

[Turing machine simulator](//morphett.info/turing?2c9e01f05228fa416b6b0bfcbbacb7c1)

I do not know if this counts as the correct output, since it has 82 leading spaces.

I do not know if this respects the 4 GB limit, so, if it doesn't, then it's non-competitive and just for showcase. The output is 1e100 bytes, so that should be deducted from the memory byte count. The final byte count is 82 bytes.

Here is an explanation:

The first 80 lines of code are 80 different states that generate the base-19<sup>1</sup> loop count `6EC1BCF4688309GH806H932ADCC44EEG6DE0FE9FAHDE66DGH108C9G3623E045A0H7A95AB594CE99A`.

The next 19 lines of code are the counter state, which decrements the count every time a character is printed.

The next 6 lines are the printer state, which appends an `=`.

Finally, the last 2 lines are the cleaner state, which are needed to make sure the only output is `=====...=====`. Leading/trailing spaces do not count as output, since they are unavoidable side-effects.

The program then halts.

<sup><sup>1</sup>I did the math for that.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

## Whispers v3, <s>48..40</s> 35 bytes

*+ more oomph thanks to [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393/leo)!*

```
> 100
>> 1*1
>> Output 2
>> For 2 3
```

Prints \$10^{100}\$ copies of \$10^{100}\$ copies of \$100^{100}\$.

[<s>Don't</s> try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsHQwIDLDkhpGYIo/9KSgtISBSMQ2y2/SMFIwfj/fwA)

**Explanation:**

In Whispers, the last line is executed first. The other lines are executed when they are referenced in an executing line.

<sup>1</sup> `> 100` Integer \$100\$.

<sup>2</sup> `>> 1*1`
Result of *line 1* multiplied with itself.

<sup>3</sup> `>> Output 2`
Prints *line 2*.

<sup>4</sup> `>> For 2 3`
Executes *line 3* \$n\$ times, where \$n\$ is the result of *line 2*.

Comment: Oh no, I tried it online..

Comment: I would change `Output 1` to `Output 2` for some more oomph

Comment: @Leo you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 4):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), <strike>112</strike> 70 bytes (5×14=70 codels)

```
vnfjlvudabknrTvn           Fv c ijjbrlk  Ev c?sj????d  Cv c ciqdlttdui
```

[image: Program]

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJyFjUEKhDAMRe-S9V801WrtVaQL0QqCzgidWQ1zdxNFkdkMCeHzebx8qH8OiULbMmpwAY8KDAe2YEklGuktTMRBNP-22ElNbr9GlF5FVswXVd8pD_3L97Un6H50To2lAhWMjAStYgTltFIgAs3TcoSUewpjN-cEmh7r-6X1dwO0WzWZ)

**Changes**

- -42 codels - thanks to @emanresu-a for getting me a different idea to set-up the stack.

**Explanation**

1. Outer path

   Setting up the stack by pushing 5 and 2, then multiplying and duplicating until we have 10⁴, 10³² and 10⁶⁴. Lastly multiplying those to 10¹⁰⁰.

   [image: Outer Loop]
2. Loop

   Looping a googol times and printing a 1 on each repetition. (same as before, just flipped)

   [image: Inner Loop]

   ```
   command  -> stack after
   push 1      [n, 1]
   push 2      [n, 1, 2]
   push 1      [n, 1, 2, 1]
   roll        [1, n]
   push 1      [1, n, 1]
   out(Number) [1, n]
   push 1      [1, n, 1]
   subtract    [1, n-1]
   duplicate   [1, n-1, n-1]
   push 3      [1, n-1, n-1, 3]
   push 1      [1, n-1, n-1, 3, 1]
   roll        [n-1, 1, n-1]
   greater     [n-1, 0 || 1]
   pointer     [n-1]
   ```

**Simple Version for proving that it works**

Setting up stack with 10 and looping exactly the same for getting 10 1s as output.

[Try simple loop online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJyFjkkKgDAMRe_y139hne1VxIVoBcEJqivx7jZ26UQ-IYTHS3Y0c2ugy1Ixo4qYU32logeLv3hSpuTqgTM7QcyQKZ-pnLfz4ZsuEWMsQMrAlZDXfxVhzQINEEM_-sHYBrqrB2uIflq2VdbHCWPvN1s)

**Findings (by a 1st time user of Piet)**

- It's a refreshing exercise working with a stack-based 2D language and getting a picture out in the end.
- It's fun to try and squeeze it as small as possible, but probably there is a lot more to get :D
- I will most likely use this again on other golfing challenges

Comment: Nice! Might it be shorter to include some more `dup`s in the outer path so 2^4, 2^8  etc get pushed to the stack and can be multiplied?

Comment: Great idea, now I see potential improvements.
I will later try to make it smaller

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>45</s> 43 bytes

```
r 0=[]
r i='1':r(i-1)
main=putStr.r$10^100
```

Answer (score 3):

### Pyke, <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
TTX^V
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=TTX%5EV)

Untested as it crashes my browser. The first 4 chars generate 10^100 and `V` prints out that many newlines. Test with `100V`.

Answer (score 3):

### Racket 36 bytes

```
(for((i(expt 10 100)))(display "1"))
```

Output:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111...
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JAISBaL](https://github.com/SocraticPhoenix/JAISBaL/wiki), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/SocraticPhoenix/JAISBaL/wiki/JAISBaL-Character-Encoding)

```
˖Q
```

Chrome can't read all the symbols, and I'm not sure about other browsers, so here's a picture:

[image]

Explanation:

```
# \# enable verbose parsing #\
10^100       \# [0] push 10^100 onto the stack #\
for          \# [1] start for loop #\
    space    \# [2] print a space #\
```

Pretty simple.... just prints a googol spaces. Three instructions, but the googol constant is two bytes.

(Written in version 3.0.5)

Comment: This is 6 UTF-8 bytes. Which encoding are you using?

Comment: "bytes" does link to it...

Comment: Gah, sorry. I have a userscript that makes links look like regular text.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that was possible, okay :)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien umm, why?

Comment: @Cyoce It's accidental to the userscript, not integral.

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, 20 bytes

Straightforward. Only eight lines are displayed at once, and previous lines do not stay in memory. Because `ᴇ100` is unsupported, we must loop from `-ᴇ99` to `9ᴇ99`. Then, if `I!=0`, display the string (which, by the way, is 3). This way, we print it exactly `ᴇ100` times.

```
For(I,-ᴇ99,9ᴇ99:If I:Disp 3:End
```

Comment: Are you sure the variable "I" is precise enough to store 99 digits?

Comment: Alright, yes, I should be enough to hold that, although it would only display up to 14 if using "Disp", but we don't actually output it, only check if it does not equal zero. Also, you're right about the symbol, but I figured you would understand what I mean. I'll copy that into my post now.

Comment: I have never encountered a version of BASIC with infinite integers but that doesn't even matter as your loop doesn't execute nearly enough times.

Comment: Umm yea, there's no infinite integers here. Integers must be within +-10^100

Comment: numbers in TI-Basic are some sort of floats. I don't know the detail, but with some quick testing, a precision of 1 can only be achieved up to ~1e12 (try `1e13+1-1e13`)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>85</s> 83 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to ETHproductions!*

```
eval([...Array(i=100)].map(_=>`for($${--i}=0;$${i}++<10;)`).join``+"console.log()")
```

This prints 1e100 newlines.

The inner part generates this program, which is thereafter evaluated.

```
for($0=0;$0++<10;)for($1=0;$1++<10;)for($2=0;$2++<10;)for($3=0;$3++<10;)for($4=0;$4++<10;)for($5=0;$5++<10;)for($6=0;$6++<10;)for($7=0;$7++<10;)for($8=0;$8++<10;)for($9=0;$9++<10;)for($10=0;$10++<10;)for($11=0;$11++<10;)for($12=0;$12++<10;)for($13=0;$13++<10;)for($14=0;$14++<10;)for($15=0;$15++<10;)for($16=0;$16++<10;)for($17=0;$17++<10;)for($18=0;$18++<10;)for($19=0;$19++<10;)for($20=0;$20++<10;)for($21=0;$21++<10;)for($22=0;$22++<10;)for($23=0;$23++<10;)for($24=0;$24++<10;)for($25=0;$25++<10;)for($26=0;$26++<10;)for($27=0;$27++<10;)for($28=0;$28++<10;)for($29=0;$29++<10;)for($30=0;$30++<10;)for($31=0;$31++<10;)for($32=0;$32++<10;)for($33=0;$33++<10;)for($34=0;$34++<10;)for($35=0;$35++<10;)for($36=0;$36++<10;)for($37=0;$37++<10;)for($38=0;$38++<10;)for($39=0;$39++<10;)for($40=0;$40++<10;)for($41=0;$41++<10;)for($42=0;$42++<10;)for($43=0;$43++<10;)for($44=0;$44++<10;)for($45=0;$45++<10;)for($46=0;$46++<10;)for($47=0;$47++<10;)for($48=0;$48++<10;)for($49=0;$49++<10;)for($50=0;$50++<10;)for($51=0;$51++<10;)for($52=0;$52++<10;)for($53=0;$53++<10;)for($54=0;$54++<10;)for($55=0;$55++<10;)for($56=0;$56++<10;)for($57=0;$57++<10;)for($58=0;$58++<10;)for($59=0;$59++<10;)for($60=0;$60++<10;)for($61=0;$61++<10;)for($62=0;$62++<10;)for($63=0;$63++<10;)for($64=0;$64++<10;)for($65=0;$65++<10;)for($66=0;$66++<10;)for($67=0;$67++<10;)for($68=0;$68++<10;)for($69=0;$69++<10;)for($70=0;$70++<10;)for($71=0;$71++<10;)for($72=0;$72++<10;)for($73=0;$73++<10;)for($74=0;$74++<10;)for($75=0;$75++<10;)for($76=0;$76++<10;)for($77=0;$77++<10;)for($78=0;$78++<10;)for($79=0;$79++<10;)for($80=0;$80++<10;)for($81=0;$81++<10;)for($82=0;$82++<10;)for($83=0;$83++<10;)for($84=0;$84++<10;)for($85=0;$85++<10;)for($86=0;$86++<10;)for($87=0;$87++<10;)for($88=0;$88++<10;)for($89=0;$89++<10;)for($90=0;$90++<10;)for($91=0;$91++<10;)for($92=0;$92++<10;)for($93=0;$93++<10;)for($94=0;$94++<10;)for($95=0;$95++<10;)for($96=0;$96++<10;)for($97=0;$97++<10;)for($98=0;$98++<10;)for($99=0;$99++<10;)console.log()
```

Now, for a proof of correctness, we'll use some induction. Let's substitute the initial 100 for other values, generically *N*. I claim that inserting *N* will yield 10<sup>*N*</sup> newlines. Let's pipe the result of this to `wc -l`, which counts the number of newlines in the input. We'll use this modified but equivalent script that takes input *N*:

```
eval([...Array(+process.argv[2])].map(_=>`for($${i}=0;$${i++}++<10;)`,i=0).join``+"console.log()")
```

Now, here's some output:

```
C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents\Programming
λ node googol.es6 1 | wc -l
10

C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents\Programming
λ node googol.es6 2 | wc -l
100

C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents\Programming
λ node googol.es6 3 | wc -l
1000

C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents\Programming
λ node googol.es6 4 | wc -l
10000
```

We can see that this transforms the input *N* for small values to 10<sup>*N*</sup> newlines.

Here is an example output for *N* = 1:

```
C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents\Programming
λ node googol.es6 1











C:\Users\Conor O'Brien\Documents\Programming
λ
```

Comment: Nice. Save a couple bytes with ```eval([...Array(i=100)].map(_=>`for($${--i}=0;$${i}++<10;)`).join``+"console.log()")```

Comment: @ETHproductions thanks! :D

Comment: P.S. I count 83 bytes ;)

Comment: Another example [here](https://repl.it/EKHF/1). Not sure if it's useful to anyone else, but I wasn't quite sure how this worked and wrote a wrapper function for the eval'd function to play with. You can clearly see the program counting to 10^n, where n is the number of loops evaluated. I set a return condition so it breaks well before googol; change the variable used in that condition to count through different loop levels. Also, a nitpick: your second code sample shows the outer loop being $0, going down to $99; it should be reversed, with $99 being the outer loop.

Comment: @MichaelS true. I will change it the next chance I get.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>48</s> <s>30</s> 25 bytes

```
For[n=1,n++<Echo@1*^100,]
```

Output:

```
>> 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>> 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>> 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>> 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>> 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
etc.
```

Comment: Can't test right now, but how about `For[n=0,n++<10^100,Echo[]]`?

Comment: I'd consider the leading `>>` part of the output. They're printed if you use `Echo` on the console.

Comment: @MartinEnder Whoops, fixed

Comment: How about `Echo@0&~Array~10^100;` for 21 bytes?

Answer (score 3):

## Fortran 95, Free-form, Recursive, 117 bytes

```
Program M
Call R(99)
END
Recursive Subroutine R(L)
IF(L)3,1,1
1 DO 2 I=1,10
2 Call R(L-1)
RETURN
3 PRINT*,0
END
```

Prints a googol of lines containing

```
          0
```

## Fortran 90, Recursive, 149 bytes

```
     CallR(99)
     END
     RecursiveSubroutineR(L)
     IF(L)3,1,1
   1 DO2I=1,10
   2 CallR(L-1)
     RETURN
   3 PRINT*,0
     END
```

Recursively calling 100 nested loops, each 10 iterations,
makes exactly one googol. N, L, and the loop counters all fit
in byte-sized integers.

Tested by replacing 99 with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and noting that
in each case the resulting line count from "wc" has n+1 zeros.

## Fortran II, IV, 66, or 77, 231 bytes:

```
      N=2*10**9
      DO1I0=1,5**10
      DO1I=1,N
      DO1J=1,N
      DO1K=1,N
      DO1L=1,N
      DO1M=1,N
      DO1I1=1,N
      DO1J1=1,N
      DO1K1=1,N
      DO1L1=1,N
      DO1M1=1,N
1     PRINT2
2     FORMAT(X)
      END
```

Prints a googol of newlines.

All of these programs will run on 32-bit machines; in fact, the recursive versions would work just fine on a 16-bit machine. One could use fewer loops in the brute-force version by running on an old Cray with its 60-bit integers. Here, ten nested loops of 2*10^9 inside one loop of 5^10 (9765625) equals 10 ^ 100 total iterations.

None of the versions uses any memory to speak of other than the object code itself, the counters, one copy of the output string, and, in the recursive version, a 100-level return stack.

Check the factors by comparing

```
bc<<<2000000000\^10*5\^10
bc<<<10\^100
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `H`, <s>4</s> 3 bytes

*Crossed out 4 is still regular 4*

```
↵(,
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=H&code=%E2%86%B5%28%2C&inputs=&header=&footer=)
Prints \$10^{100}\$ newlines.

```
↵   # 10 **...
    # 100 (Stack preset by flag)
 (, # Times print nothing (with a newline)
```

Comment: -1 byte using `H` flag: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=H&code=%E2%86%B5%28%2C&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: @astonearachnid I completely forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
V^T100G
```

[Link](//pyth.herokuapp.com?code=V%5ET100pG)

Solution is tested with small output, but it should print `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` 1e100 times.

For some reason, the `p` was unneeded, as 31343 (Maltysen) [said](/questions/97975/output-a-googol-copies-of-a-string/97991?noredirect=1#comment238769_97991).

Comment: Why is the p needed?

Comment: @Maltysen I think because of the 4 GB limit.

Comment: Why? Cuz of the buffer? Doesn't that automatically flush?

Comment: @Maltysen I don't know, the online interpreter does not have immediate output functionality. It might flush, it might not...

Comment: Its working locally without the `p`

Comment: @Maltysen Oh, I thought it took more than 4 gigabytes of RAM, but it apparently doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 7 Bytes

**New** (Competing)

```
V^T*TTG
```

**Explanation**

```
G=The alphabet
Repeat 10^(10*10) times
    print(G)
```

---

**Old** (Non Competing) 7 Bytes

```
*G^T*TT
```

**Explanation**

```
G=The alphabet
G*(10^(10*10))==G*10^100
```

Comment: This doesn't comply with the 4 GiB remory limit.

Comment: @Dennis I fixed it

Comment: Not a golfing advice, but I don't think `*TT` is any shorter than a plain `100`.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>198</s> <s>179</s> 155 bytes

```
import java.math.*;class a{void A(a[]x){for(BigInteger b=BigInteger.ZERO;!(b=b.add(BigInteger.ONE)).equals(BigInteger.TEN.pow(100));)System.out.print(x);}}
```

Prints (`x` == `null` ? `null` : a string that starts with `[La;@` or something like that) 10<sup>100</sup> times in O(forever) time.

Comment: You have a `class`, but no `public static void main(String[]a)` method. As for golfing tips: you can replace the `new BigInteger("0")`, `new BigInteger("1")` and `new BigInteger("10")` with `BigInteger.ZERO`, `BigInteger.ONE` and `BigInteger.TEN`; you can replace `import java.math.BigInteger;` with `import java.math.*;`.

Comment: No need for imports: something similar to this should work: `java.math.BigInteger b=null;for(b=b.ZERO;!(b=b.add(b.ONE)).equals(b.TEN.pow(100);)System.out.print(x);`

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire That gives me a NullReferenceException, possibly because `b` is null.

Comment: @Xanderhall you probably tried this in C# (because you said NRE, not NPE). I can't test the Java version right now so I can't tell what's wrong. In any case, I said "should work", not "will work". The idea to take is that you can have static method calls on instance references, even null ones.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I tried it in Java. I don't code in C#.

Comment: @Xanderhall I "only" missed one parenthesis, so "something similar" is totally good enough in my first comment. The full *program*, for 126 bytes is the following: `class A{void A(A[]x){java.math.BigInteger b=null;for(b=b.ZERO;!(b=b.add(b.ONE)).equals(b.TEN.pow(100));)System.out.print(x);}}`. And it works. I tested it before posting.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I would've sworn I copied it exactly as it was and it didn't work (and that was after fixing the bracket), hence my comment. It's working now.

Comment: @Xanderhall (my last comment on this issue) you probably encountered [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert).

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 32 bytes

```
for i in range(10**100):print()
```

Alternate solution, 33 bytes:

```
[print()for i in range(10**100)]
```

Comment: In Python 2 this is a particularly great answer.

Comment: Not so much, @Lembik. In Python 2, `range(10**100)` creates a list of numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4, ...]`, which results in `OverflowError: range() result has too many items`. This would work in Python 2 with a call to `xrange()` instead, and works in Python 3 since `xrange()` was renamed to `range()`, and the original `range()` that generated a list was deprecated.

Comment: @JamesMurphyb Yes I know that. I was trying to be funny about the impractability of codegolf answers.

Comment: Sorry. I have trouble reading humor in a lot of SE comments.

Comment: I've undeleted this, and 4 other valid, positively-scoring answers you deleted in quick succession, under suspicion it may be vandalism. Please note that answers should not be deleted without good reason, as, once posted, they are subject to SE's [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing). If there is a good reason these answers should be deleted, please raise a flag for moderators to handle.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 153 bytes

```java
import java.math.*;interface M{static void main(String[]a){for(BigInteger i=BigInteger.ZERO;!i.add(i.ONE).equals(i.TEN.pow(100));)System.out.print(1);}}
```

Output: 1e100 1s

I know there is another Java answer which is also pretty close. Mine's got a main and is still shorter though.

This is my first code-golf entry. Tips appreciated.

Comment: This can be golfed to 117 bytes by using lambda. You still need to include the import, however. `import java.math.*;()->{for(BigInteger i=BigInteger.ZERO;!i.add(i.ONE).equals(i.TEN.pow(100));)System.out.print(1);};`

Comment: @BasicallyAlanTuring Actually my `javac` won't let me compile this.

Comment: Update your Java then. Also, this is not complete compilable code. Just the bare minimum allowed for an entry.

Comment: @BasicallyAlanTuring Got Java 8. I guess functions are not allowed by the OP.

Comment: The code I have given you is not a complete program.. It's just what's required to be a valid CG answer.

Comment: @BasicallyAlanTuring Functions are enough even if the OP doesn't state so? Thank you!

Comment: Yes generally. Unless the OP specifically asks for a full program.

Comment: @BasicallyAlanTuring He actually stated he's interested in seeing programs.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. Try substituting 100 by 1. It should print 10 copies of "1", but it never stops. This is because ```i.add(i.ONE)``` makes a new ```BigDecimal``` and leaves ```i``` untouched.

Comment: You can substitute ```i.add(i.ONE``` by ```(i=i.add(i.ONE))``` (+4 chars) to fix it, but it will still print only 10**100-1 ones.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```
for($a=str_pad(e,99,0);T^$a++;)echo!0;
```

Run like this:

```
php -r 'for($a=str_pad(e,99,0);T^$a++;)echo!0;' 2>/dev/null
```

## STDERR (34 bytes)

If a variant with output to STDERR is valid, then this outputs `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant T - assumed 'T' in Command line code on line 1` a googol times.

```
php -r 'for($a=str_pad(@e,99,0);T^++$a;);'
```

## Explanation

```
for (
    $a = str_pad("e", 99, "0"); // Creates a string "e000" (98 zeroes).
    "T" ^ $a++;                 // Increment the string, binary XOR with
                                // "T": when the alphabetic part of the 
                                // string becomes "da" this results in 
                                // falsy "0", ending the loop.
)
    echo!0;                     // Print a single "1".
```

Note that the alphabetic part iterates from `e..z` (22), `aa..az` (26), `ba..bz` (26), `ca..cz` (26) for a total of 100, or a `1` with 2 zeroes. So only 98 zeroes need to be added to arrive at `1E100`. The loop stops only when the alphabetic part is 2 digits and the second digit becomes  `d`. The `d` is conveniently skipped when it's only 1 digit (since it starts at `e`).

## Perf

This doesn't consume a ridiculous amount of resources (in fact very little) and runs fast.

## Tweaks

- Saved a byte by using 2 alphabetic chars so less padding characters (99 vs 101)
- Added a variant using STDERR, saving 5 bytes

Comment: Your code must be within `<?php` tags, even if it is a pure .php file. However, in a PHP file, you can omit the closing `?>` tag. Just saying.

Comment: @ckjbgames wrong. Ever tried running code with `php -r`? In any case, [here's](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2424/38392) the relevant discussion about that.

Comment: You would need to if it was meant to be on a webpage.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 18 bytes

```
say 1 for ^10**100
```

Notes:

- Perl 6 integers have no upper limit, so `10**100` calculates the googol just fine.
- The `^n` syntax is short for `0 ..^ n`, which constructs a range from 0 (inclusive) to n (not inclusive), which conceptually contains n integers but is stored as a memory-efficient `Range` object.
- The `for` loop iterates over it without keeping already iterated elements in memory, so the program's RAM usage will remain pretty stable - and far below 4 GB - throughout its runtime.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, <del>72</del> 71 bytes

Prints 10^100 at signs.
Saved 1 byte thanks to @FlipTack.

```
printf '@%.0s' $(eval echo $(seq 1 $(echo 10^100 | bc | tr "\n" "\0")))
```

WARNING: This is probably *extremely* slow.

---

This is my first code golf, so I hope I did well.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. You don't take the string to print as input, you can print _any string you want_ a googol times, whatever string is shortest for you to print

Comment: @FlipTack Thanks! One byte saved.

Answer (score 2):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 3815+3 = 3818 bytes

+3 bytes for flag `-w`

```
 *
,xZ.
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
 K  K
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
 K `K
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
 K  K
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K `K
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
 K `K
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K `K
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K `K
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K `K
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
 K `K
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
 K  K
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
 K  K
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K `K
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
 K  K
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@'*|
 K aK
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@'*|
 K eK
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@'*|
 K fK
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
 K K
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
 K K
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
 K K
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@' |
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@'*}T
,xZ~<
`@','
 K K
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'|
 K `K
,xZ~<
`@','
,xZ<
`@'|
,xZ<
`@'`.
,xZ~'
`@'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Za9DoIwFIV3nqIbSUN4Agf3rk5ORQTBydGh@upVSmJioXpPf0xMup00l6/tuYcL7TBetGa8qK77upDbUk1qE1MxwUSGZmiG/jdU1pO8G12V5FJm0DP7tbKqAehb6RMvMTxwFacxDga2jNJVgO1eGMdDluWrVdZpUFcc/BS2u05K0bBBBFsITQFGABp2mfZVxScXnkfo2KSGwIFUwE7EdzUkph@38Bo2v7ZfxHQ8CtynsZAdXwu44TcRu7qkd95zmBSDFIN4eYleROwqHB6op9ZOWDjRApL7WNf5bUf5UoVfBfoLKSetdXNoj11/GsbzAw)

Oof.

It's a beeping massive binary counter: 333 bits are needed to express 1 googol, so there are 333 half-adders `@` and 333 registers `Z`. (Actually only 100/log<sub>10</sub>(2) = ~332.2 bits are required, but this solution can't take advantage of those massive savings). There are also a few periodic caches `K`, which are required for this to even run correctly.

Note about the TIO: instead of using `-w` (which is a fake stdin consisting of infinite null bytes), it uses regular input. The result is that it terminates at the end of input, rather than attempting to outlive the universe by a factor of 10<sup>80</sup>.

The termination condition is encoded by the presence or absence of `~` near the `Z`s. If you worked from the bottom up, writing a '1' when you see a `~`, and '0' when you don't, you'll have the binary representation for 1 googol.

[Here is a TIO that only prints 100 times.](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/P1ErVSuNS6ciSo8rwUG9BsSyAbES9EDMOjBbRx0ujF2BVm0ImKMO4vz//1@3HAA) This one does use `-w`, showing off the termination condition.

Also scattered around are `*a`, `*e`, and `*f`. These work together to produce an ASCII '1' for the output. If they were absent, null characters would be printed instead.

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck, 45 bytes

```
->-[[->+<]+>-]<[[>-<-[>[----->]]>[<]<].<[+]<]
```

It outputs 254×250<sup>255</sup> null bytes and exits with an error.

## Brainfuck, <del>50</del> 48 bytes, without errors

```
>>>->-[[->+<]+>-]<[[>-<-[>[----->]]>[<]<]<[.+]<]
```

It outputs 254×250<sup>255</sup> times `\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff`, and 1524×250<sup>255</sup> bytes in total.

Comment: How the error, pointer <0?

Comment: @l4m2 Yes. I think that's the only way to error in a controlled manner in Brainfuck.

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 26 bytes

```sh
eval repeat\ a{0..99}+10 @
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/tSwxR6EotSA1sSRGIbHaQE/P0rJW29BAweH/fwA)

*-2 thanks to @GammaFunction*

- `repeat\ a{0..99}+10`: construct the string `repeat a0+10 repeat a1+10 ... repeat a99+10`

  - `a0` through `a99` are undefined and are treated as `0`, so `a0+10` always evaluates to 10
- append `@`
- `eval`uate that string, which is 100 nested loops and then on each iteration we execute the command `@`, which doesn't exist, so it prints `(eval):1: command not found: @`

To be perfectly honest, I'm surprised the existing shell answers are so bad

Comment: You can remove the last escaped space for **26 bytes**.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=UXBMcEw=&input=), 5 bytes

```
QpLpL
```

I used a similar approach found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97980/101119). This program prints **10<sup>200</sup>** copies of the string `"`, or **10<sup>100</sup>** copies of the string containing **10<sup>100</sup>** copies of the string `"`. The output of the program would look something like this:

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""......about 1e200 copies later......"""""""""""""""""""""""""""
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=UXBMcEw=&input=)

### Explanation

```
QpLpL
Q     - The string consisting of " (quotation mark)
 p    - That string gets repeated some amount of times, specified on next line
  LpL - L is the number 100, and LpL does 100 to the power of 100, which is 1e200
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 25 bytes

```bash
bc<<<'for(;i++<10^100;)9'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PynZxsZGPS2/SMM6U1vbxtAgztDAwFrTUv3/fwA)

## [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html), 18 bytes

```bash
for(;++i<10^100;)9
```

Why is TIO broken so it won't work unless coding in header?

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0r@n5ZfpGGtrZ1pY2gQZ2hgYK1p@f//fwA)

Comment: it's because bc expects a newline at the end of the file, add a newline in the footer to put the code in the _Code_ section, also the bc version is one iteration short of a googol, [here](https://tio.run/##S0r@/z8tv0jDOlNb28bQIM7QwMBa0/I/138A)'s a fix

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╡¢xYΓU
```

Uncompressed and explained:

```
AJ|A          10^100
    D         For that many iterations
     1p       print 1
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=AJ%7CAD1p&i=)

Answer (score 2):

## [MUMPS](http://www.cs.uni.edu/%7Eokane/), 20 bytes

```
 f %=1:1:"1E100" w 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy3NLSj@/18hTUHV1tDK0ErJ0NXQwEBJoVzB8P9/AA)

- There is a leading space so that `f` is interpreted as a command rather than a line label.
- `f %=1:1:"1E100"` assigns 1 to the variable `%` and increments it by 1 on each loop until it reaches a googol. `f` is short for the `for` command. Numbers in scientific notation have to be written as strings in standard M, hence the quotes.
- `w 1` prints 1 and is executed once per loop. `w` is short for the `write` command.

This can be reduced to 18 bytes in GT.M where the quotes aren't necessary for `1E100` to be interpreted as a number.

```
 f %=1:1:1E100 w 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 20 bytes

```factor
100 10^ [ bl ] times
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoZdWmpdckpmfV6yQmQ8WUbD@b2hgoGBoEKcQrZCUoxCrUJKZm1r8/z8A)

- `100 10^ [ ... ] times` Call `[ ... ]` a googol times.
- `bl` Output a space.

Answer (score 1):

## C# - <s>127</s> <s>123</s> 98 bytes

```
using System;using b=Numerics.BigInteger;void f(){for(b n=b.Pow(10,100);n-->0;)Console.Write(0);}}
```

- 1 byte from [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!
- 24 bytes from [Phaeze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/19547/phaeze)!

Prints 10^100 copies of `0`.

Comment: You can golf it by 1 byte by changing `n>0;n--` to `n-->0;`. +1 for the rest. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I can also save bytes by turning this into a shorter function, since OP didn't mention "full program". Thanks! :)

Comment: Also you can change your using to `using b= System.Numerics.BigInteger` and use the alias in the rest of the code

Comment: This should work `using System;using b=Numerics.BigInteger;void f(){for(b n=b.Pow(10,100);n-->0;)Console.Write(0);}}` for 98 bytes. :)

Comment: @Phaeze Thanks! Haven't even edited the previous edit in yet, but will do today :)

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp, 33

```
(dotimes(i(expt 10 100))(terpri))
```

Print newlines.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3, 55 bytes

Dependency: `Foundation` for `pow`(73 bytes if you count import statement)

`stride(from:0,to:pow(10,100),by:1).map{_ in print(1)}`

I know there is [another answer above](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98009/61427). However, `pow(10,100.0)` generates error message: `fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because the result would be greater than Int.max`, and it also requires `Foundation` as well

Comment: Yes, necessary imports are always counted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dip](https://github.com/mcparadip/Dip), 8 bytes

```
TT*T^(¹p
```

Prints googol newlines.

Explanation:

```
TT       # Pushes 10 twice
             # Stack: [10, 10]
  *      # Multiply 10 by 10
             # Stack: [100]
   T     # Push 10
             # Stack: [100, 10]
    ^    # Raise 10 to 100
             # Stack: [Googol]
     (   # Do Googol times
             # Stack: []
      ¹  # Push ""
             # Stack: [""]
       p # Print
             # Stack: []
```

Better version that puts to use some features released after this challenge: (4 bytes)

```
UX(q
```

Explanation:

```
U    # Push 100
         # Stack: [100]
 X   # Raise 10 to 100
         # Stack: [Googol]
  (  # Repeat Googol times
         # Stack: []
   q # Print a newline
         # Stack: []
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 36 bytes

```
(doseq[i(range(.pow 100M 50))](prn))
```

Using java interlop cuts it down from original `(reduce *'(repeat 10 100))` since clojure core does not have exponent.
dotimes can only work with longs as was pointed out in comment, sadly; I had to resort to lazy seq (+5 bytes).

Comment: `dotimes` requires long as a parameter doesn't it?

Comment: It works with any N that returns TRUE for `(number? N)`, rounding or dropping fractions when needed.

Comment: https://goo.gl/xjwj0e
it casts it to `long`. it agrees with the results that I get when I try to run your code, it fails with IllegalArgumentException trying to cast that number to `long`

Comment: You are right, I had an overwritten core dotimes with some math package. I will edit with something that works in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp, 37 bytes

```
(loop repeat(expt 10 100)do(print'x))
```

Nothing fancy. Print X followed by newline 10^100 times.

Answer (score 1):

## Sed + bash, 107 bytes

```
sed "s/Z/\;done/g;s/\([A-L]\)/\1=n\;while((\1--))\;do /g"<<<"n=10;An=10**9;BCDEFGHIJKLpwdZZZZZZZZZZZZ"|bash
```

By removing the "|bash" at the end, you can see that the bash script generated (with newlines added for readability) is

```
n=10;A=n;while((A--));do n=10**9;B=n;while((B--));do C=n;while((C--));do
D=n;while((D--));do E=n;while((E--));do F=n;while((F--));do G=n;while((G--));do
H=n;while((H--));do I=n;while((I--));do J=n;while((J--));do K=n;while((K--));do
L=n;while((L--));do pwd;done;done;done;done;done;done;done;done;done;done;done;
done
```

which is similar to my original bash solution, below, except that it runs 11 loops of 10^9 nested in one loop of 10, for a total of 10^100 iterations.  It never uses a value greater than 10^9, which fits in 32 bits. Each output line
is generated with the shell builtin "pwd" instead of "echo", to save a byte.

Tested by changing 10**9 to "2" or "3" and verifying that the script generates 10 * N^11 lines.

## Bash, 312 bytes

```
n=2*10**9
a=9765625;while((a--));do
b=n;while((b--));do c=n;while((c--));do d=n;while((d--));do e=n;while((e--));do
f=n;while((f--));do g=n;while((g--));do h=n;while((h--));do i=n;while((i--));do
j=n;while((j--));do k=n;while((k--));do echo "Hello, World!"
done;done;done;done;done;done;done;done;done;done;done
```

(2*10^9)^10 * 9765725 is exactly one googol.

This needs no memory because it doesn't store anything other than the 11 counters and one copy of the "Hello, World!" string.  The counters are integers that never exceed 32 bits.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to do this with a recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

## LiveCode, 83 bytes

```
on g c
   if c=100 then
      put 1 after fld 1
   else
      repeat 10
         g c+1
      end repeat
   end if
end g
```

Logically pretty straightforward, but validated by changing the test value for c. Set it to 1, you get ten 1's. Set it to 2, you get 100. Set it to 3 you get 1,000, etc.

LiveCode automatically formats with leading spaces, but it's not required for the code to work.

The argument c will default to empty, and in LiveCode it's perfectly fine to add 1 to empty (and results in 1).

LiveCode can write to stdout, but it's a visual environment and putting text into a field is more common.

Answer (score 1):

## [LOLCODE](https://repl.it/languages/LOLCODE), 224 bytes

```
HAI 1.2
I HAS A n ITZ A NUMBR
n R 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
IM IN YR loop UPPIN YR v TIL BOTH SAEM v AN n
BTW THIS WHERE I PRINT
VISIBLE "HAI!!1"
IM OUTTA YR loop
KTHXBYE
```

I had absolutely no idea how to calculate `10100`, so why not just write it out? *Apparently, there's no `^` operator or power function in LOLCODE.*

I didn't count the bytes for the `BTW` part, since it's a comment for explaining the code. *"explain"*

Also, [my ressource](https://esolangs.org/wiki/LOLCODE) didn't quite explain how datatypes work in-depth, so we can only assume that `NUMBR` can store this much.

Comment: Try `I HAS A b ITZ A NUMBR` `b R 10` `I HAS A n ITZ A NUMBR` `n R PRODUKT OF b AN PRODUKT OF b AN n` instead of using `n R 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.`

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 9 bytes

```
2╤╤DW;Y.D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@2/0aOoSIHIJt47Uc/n/HwA)

This takes a *really* long time to run. [Here](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@2/0aOoSl3DrSD2X//8B) is a faster version that only prints 100 zeroes.

Explanation:

```
2╤╤DW;Y.D
2╤╤         push 10**(10**2)
   D        subtract 1
    W       while the value on top of the stack is truthy:
     ;Y.      duplicate it, boolean negate it (0 if truthy, 1 if falsey), pop it and print it
        D     decrement the other copy
            (after the while loop finished, (10**100)-1 zeroes will have been printed, separated by newlines)
            implicitly print the only stack value (0), followed by a newline
```

Comment: Does this fit within the memory requirements of the challenge? `sys.getsizeof(1)` returns 28, and so storing a googol copies of 1 would take `2.8 × 10^89 TB`, but the challenge restricts memory to 4GB. I may be wrong though, I don't know how Actually is interpreted.

Comment: @FlipTack In Python (the language that Actually is written in), small integers (under `256`, I believe) are not unique objects - there is only ever one `1`. Thus, this program just contains a googol references to `1`, which are much smaller than the actual object. I don't know the memory impact of multiple references to `1`, though, so it may still violate the memory limit. I'll change it to something that definitely doesn't run afoul.

Comment: I don't think storing a googol of _anything_ is possible, whether it be integers or references. Even just storing a googol bits needs `1.25 × 1087` terabytes. So the new solution seems more sensible.

Comment: I meant `1.25 x 10^87` (missed the exponent)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 5 bytes

Non-competing as the language postdates the challenge.

```
THe:"
```

Prints **10<sup>100</sup>** newlines. You can [**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@x/ikWql9P8/AA), but output is truncated at 100KB, and the site becomes very unresponsive when you run it.

```
T      \ Push 10
 H     \ Push 100
  e    \ Exponentiate - pops both and computes 10 ^ 100
   :   \ Pop the googol and that many times do:
    "  \   Print the whole stack - just a newline, as it's now empty.
```

You can verify this generates a googol by running [`THe#` in the online interpreter.](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@x/ikar8/z8A) The reference implementation is in Python and therefore has no upper limit on integer size. The googol itself does not take too much data to store, in fact you only need 333 bits to store an integer of that size (although as Python integer this seems to take up 58 bytes) - nowhere near the memory restriction on this challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## TrumpScript 189 bytes

```
I is 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000A is,I -I;We is 1000001 -1000000as long as,I >A;:say,A;I is,I -We;!America is great
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/trumpscript#@@@pkFmsYGhAB@AItEnHU0HX0zo8FWGpoYIu1PbEYoWc/Lx0hUSQKjtHa6vixEodR2tPqLbwVGtFx9zUoszkRJDu9KLUxJL//wE)

Unfortunately 100 bytes taken up by the number as TrumpScript has no exponentials

Explanation

`I is googol` (using googol for clarity) sets the variable `I` to 10^100

`A is I -I` sets `A` to 0. 0 in the code as a number is invalid as all number must be > 1000000

`We is 1000001 -1000000` assigns `we` as 1

`as long as, I > A;:` starts while loop checking that `I > 0`

`say A` prints out `0`

`I is,I -We` subtracts 1 from `I`

`America is great` ends the program

Comment: You could use multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 20 bytes

```
FOR I=1TO 1E100?NEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

## .COM, 21 bytes

```
0000h: 83 FC 9A 74 0B B9 10 27 51 E8 F4 FF 59 E2 F9 C3
0010h: B4 02 CD 21 C3                                 

    org 100h
f:  cmp sp, -2-4*25
    jz g
    mov cx, 10000
r:  push cx
    call f
    pop cx
    loop r
    ret
g:  mov ah, 2
    int 33
    ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## [HadesLang](https://github.com/Azer0s/HadesLang), 3153 bytes

I know this is really bad...but at least I tried, right?

```
for[num a in range:[0,99]]
for[num b in range:[0,99]]
for[num c in range:[0,99]]
for[num d in range:[0,99]]
for[num e in range:[0,99]]
for[num f in range:[0,99]]
for[num g in range:[0,99]]
for[num h in range:[0,99]]
for[num i in range:[0,99]]
for[num j in range:[0,99]]
for[num k in range:[0,99]]
for[num l in range:[0,99]]
for[num m in range:[0,99]]
for[num n in range:[0,99]]
for[num o in range:[0,99]]
for[num p in range:[0,99]]
for[num q in range:[0,99]]
for[num r in range:[0,99]]
for[num s in range:[0,99]]
for[num t in range:[0,99]]
for[num u in range:[0,99]]
for[num v in range:[0,99]]
for[num w in range:[0,99]]
for[num x in range:[0,99]]
for[num y in range:[0,99]]
for[num z in range:[0,99]]
for[num A in range:[0,99]]
for[num B in range:[0,99]]
for[num C in range:[0,99]]
for[num D in range:[0,99]]
for[num E in range:[0,99]]
for[num F in range:[0,99]]
for[num G in range:[0,99]]
for[num H in range:[0,99]]
for[num I in range:[0,99]]
for[num J in range:[0,99]]
for[num K in range:[0,99]]
for[num L in range:[0,99]]
for[num M in range:[0,99]]
for[num N in range:[0,99]]
for[num O in range:[0,99]]
for[num P in range:[0,99]]
for[num Q in range:[0,99]]
for[num R in range:[0,99]]
for[num S in range:[0,99]]
for[num T in range:[0,99]]
for[num U in range:[0,99]]
for[num V in range:[0,99]]
for[num W in range:[0,99]]
for[num X in range:[0,99]]
for[num Y in range:[0,99]]
for[num Z in range:[0,99]]
for[num aa in range:[0,99]]
for[num ba in range:[0,99]]
for[num ca in range:[0,99]]
for[num da in range:[0,99]]
for[num ea in range:[0,99]]
for[num fa in range:[0,99]]
for[num ga in range:[0,99]]
for[num ha in range:[0,99]]
for[num ia in range:[0,99]]
for[num ja in range:[0,99]]
for[num ka in range:[0,99]]
for[num la in range:[0,99]]
for[num ma in range:[0,99]]
for[num na in range:[0,99]]
for[num oa in range:[0,99]]
for[num pa in range:[0,99]]
for[num qa in range:[0,99]]
for[num ra in range:[0,99]]
for[num sa in range:[0,99]]
for[num ta in range:[0,99]]
for[num ua in range:[0,99]]
for[num va in range:[0,99]]
for[num wa in range:[0,99]]
for[num xa in range:[0,99]]
for[num ya in range:[0,99]]
for[num za in range:[0,99]]
for[num Aa in range:[0,99]]
for[num Ba in range:[0,99]]
for[num Ca in range:[0,99]]
for[num Da in range:[0,99]]
for[num Ea in range:[0,99]]
for[num Fa in range:[0,99]]
for[num Ga in range:[0,99]]
for[num Ha in range:[0,99]]
for[num Ia in range:[0,99]]
for[num Ja in range:[0,99]]
for[num Ka in range:[0,99]]
for[num La in range:[0,99]]
for[num Ma in range:[0,99]]
for[num Na in range:[0,99]]
for[num Oa in range:[0,99]]
for[num Pa in range:[0,99]]
for[num Qa in range:[0,99]]
for[num Ra in range:[0,99]]
for[num Sa in range:[0,99]]
for[num Ta in range:[0,99]]
for[num Ua in range:[0,99]]
for[num Va in range:[0,99]]
out:1
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
```

Comment: What is that supposed to be. Do you really need so many for loops. Also if possible provide a link so this can be tested /

Comment: @Muhammad Salman Because Hades doesn't have a datatype for BigInts yet. Unfortunatly I can't provide a link to test this :/

Comment: Is the language stable and has it been released ? If it is you should probably have it added to [TIO](https://tio.run/#). Will make it a lot easier for link providing.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
т°F,
```

Prints \$10^{100}\$ copies of `10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\n`.

[(Don't) try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//YtOhDW46//8DAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
т     # Push 100
 °    # Pop and push 10^100
  F   # Loop that many times:
   ,  #  And print the top of the stack with trailing newline;
      #  (because the stack and input are both empty, it uses the previous value, which
      #   was the 10^100)
```

Note: [the existing 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97981/52210) uses the legacy version of 05AB1E. In that answer, the `Tn` could be `т` to push 100 now as well, but the `,` won't use the previous value implicitly. (The old version of 05AB1E was built in Python 3, the new version in Elixir.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://github.com/arturo-lang/arturo), 32 bytes

```
i:10^100while[i>0][dec'i 0print]
```

Prints the number 0 with a newline a googol times.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 114 bytes

```rust
||{let i=0..10u128.pow(25);let f=|_|i.clone();for _ in i.clone().flat_map(f).flat_map(f).flat_map(f){print!("h")}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZnZNaopCuYPu/pgbMzLQ10NMzNCg1NLLQK8gv1zAy1bQGiafZ1sTXZOol5@TnpWpoWqflFynEK2TmKcCF9NJyEkvicxMLNNJwsqsLijLzShQ1lDKUNGtr/1tzpQON4qr9DwA)

Not bad for a language without built-in arbitrary precision integers. The code creates a lazily evaluated iterator 10^100 elements long and then prints h for every element in it.

```rust
||{                         // Anonymous function block
  let i=0..10u128.pow(25);  // declare i as the exclusive range from 0 to 10^25
  let f=|_|i.clone();       // anonymous function that ignores input and ouptputs i
  for _ in i.clone()        // for every value in i
            .flat_map(f)    // map every element with the function f, then flatten
            .flat_map(f)    // map again
            .flat_map(f){   // map one more time
    print!("h")             // print h
  }                         // end for loop
}                           // end fn
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$11\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 9.054 bytes

```
Rt@100mC',1
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJSdEAxMDBtQycsMSIsIiJd)

This is really impractical in Fig, as it has no explicit for loops (only an infinite while loop). I had to use a reduce as a map would eventually calculate the entire list and will make the computer run out of memory.

```
Rt@100mC',1
      mC    # The list of numbers
 t          # (Lazily) take
  @100      # 10^100 of them
R       '   # Reduce the list of a googol items
         ,1 # Ignore the reducing and print a 1
```

Comment: you really need a two-byte constant for 100.

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan there is :P Except `@@2` doesnt really parse

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 44 bytes

```c
f(n){n?f(--n),f(n-n%9):puts(f);}g(){f(900);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOs8@TUNXN09TB8jTzVO11LQqKC0p1kjTtK5N19CsTtOwNDAAsv9n5pUo5CZm5mloKlRzKQABUEbTmqv2PwA)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 45 bytes

```c
f(n){n?f(--n),f(n/9*9):puts("");}g(){f(900);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5ySmpaZl6pQUFpSrFGhqZCcX5pXoq3NlZlXAmFb/0/TyNOszrNP09DVzdOsAfL0LbUsNa3AOpSUNK1r0zU0q9M0LA0MgOz/II25iZl5GpoK1VwKQAA2RcFWwcAazAUq1ISwCoqAatM0lFRTYvKUdCDqoFIYegwtyNBkZI5fU@1/AA)

tio showed `f` call for 10, 100 and 1000

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 36 bytes

```javascript
f=(n=900)=>n?f(--n)|f(n-n%9):print()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P81WI8/W0sBA09Yuzz5NQ1c3T7MmTSNPN0/VUtOqoCgzr0RD83@ahqXmfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## ForceLang, 58 bytes

```
set k 10.pow 100
label a
set k k+-1
io.write 1
if k
goto a
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 35 bytes

Under more realistic programming circumstances, Python allows you to multiply strings by a number, as with `'x' * 100`, which would produce a string that's a hundred characters long and composed of nothing but the letter `x`.

However, it appears that Python string objects don't appreciate having indices whose values exceed the maximum of `int`. Python is content to re-cast large `int` values to a special `bignum` sort of thing, but the longest string that Python can handle is [on the order of several gigabytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739913/what-is-the-max-length-of-a-python-string), and assuming each character in Python is 1 byte, it would take [much, much more](https://www.google.com/search?q=1%20googol%20bytes%20to%20gb&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=10%5E100%20bytes%20to%20gb) memory to contain the string that would unfold from `'x'*10**100`.

As such, Python's built-in arbitrary arithmetic and the humble `while` loop allow us to produce a more practical program, which spits out one `x` per line for a googol lines. Thankfully, this proves to be shorter than the admittedly more readable `for x in xrange(10**100):`, as `range()` and `xrange()` are both limited to the largest possible value for a C `long` type, which is Python's native non-bignum `int`.

```
i=0
while i<10**100:
    print'x';i+=1
```

Comment: `i=10**100` newline `while i:print;i-=1` prints googol newlines and is 7 bytes shorter

Comment: It's also am exact copy of someone else's solution, so I'll leave it as is.

Comment: If I'm right, it's an exact copy of @FlipTack program.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](http://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

Note that Charcoal uses a [custom codepage](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page).

```
ＦＸ¹⁰¦¹⁰⁰Ｄ
```

Prints one googol newlines. Takes around 3.16887646×10⁹⁰ years to finish running.

#### Explanation

```
Ｆ        For
 Ｘ       Exponentiate
  ¹⁰¦¹⁰⁰  10, 100
Ｄ        Print (Dump) contents of canvas ("") plus newline
```

This will not freeze your computer (luckily!) because Charcoal has a 10ms minimum delay between prints by default. Charcoal used `range` as of this challenge's posting, therefore using more than 4GB of memory, but this has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## 05AB1E, 8 bytes

```
TTT*mFõ,
```

Prints googol newlines.

[Try it online! (Not recommended)](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=VFRUKm1Gw7Us&input=)

Explanation:

```
TTT      # Push 10 three times
             # Stack: [10, 10, 10]
   *     # Multiply 10 by 10
             # Stack: [10, 100]
    m    # Raise 10 to 100
             # Stack: [Googol]
     F   # Do Googol times
             # Stack: []
      õ  # Push ""
             # Stack: [""]
       , # Print
             # Stack: []
```

Comment: Not recommended? More like won't run.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP7 (64-bit), 36 bytes

```
<?=bcsub(bcpow(10,bcpow(10,100)),1);
```

Should output 10^(10^100)-1 so 10^100 times the digit 9.

As of PHP 7.0.0, there are no particular restrictions regarding the length of a string on 64-bit builds. [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: I don't think there's enough RAM in the entire universe to complete this operation. I tried with only `1e10` and it stopped after it had allocated 5 GB and then tried to allocate 18.4 exabytes. I gave it 10GB, so I was a bit short :)

Answer (score 0):

## VBA 117 bytes

```
Sub q():Dim x(100):While x(100)=0:Debug.Print:x(0)=x(0)+1:i=0:While x(i)>9:x(i)=0:i=i+1:x(i)=x(i)+1:Wend:Wend:End Sub
```

Invoke with `q`. Prints a googol newlines to immediate window. Easy to test by changing the "While x(100)" to say "While x(2)", which prints a hundred newlines.

I could use "MsgBox 0" in place of "Debug.Print" (saving 3 characters) but that would involve pressing return on the output more times than feasible, countering the whole idea of "program".

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 31 bytes

`{Eval.me(it*"1${'0'*10**100}")}`

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 11 bytes

```
"#10^100::0
```

Given enough time (and memory, although it times out on TIO instead of running out of output space), will print `10^100` copies of whatever is to the right of `0`.

### Explanation

```
"             No join on output
 #10^100      Set n to 10^100
        ::    Print the sequence from 1 to n
          0   Each item in the sequence is 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X0nZ0CDO0MDAysrg/38A)

Comment: Note current version uses `&` instead of `::`, saving 1 byte

Answer (score 0):

## BRASCA, 8 bytes

```
lH^[ho{]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVtpc9s2E/6uX4HabSXVki3naBLXcl87Sd@4reOM7U7b8TgsREISUpJgSdCyJm3/eroLHuIlEYxPzSSWCGD32QOLBbD05nIq3MfPPf8TdzzhSxLMgx5xqJy2xr5wiOQOI0mTzZgXPfapa8GfuAF/wb8Ja8UPpE9NNqLmn62WadMgIAc@DUz6Er/vtAh81tbWTiV06BGfTXggmR8QoEIuqc/pyGYBdFAdLTYmhsFdLg2jEzB73N1pqQb8rCsaamBKJm3EzpuB6jAk5xf55xSeDfKPRrlHCx77PiMzBgyoxd0JYZfMB63hVxoQc0pBVuT7fZGxD10MR1gM6P5A7YBlcL/jHrP63CUWlTR9zMfEFcoEMByYbfKASjnvdHfSLhn60MHA4UB@MQJRdrrnOzv97YvcoLHwidEjBgGmzA0d5lPJOgVSBUYVzNBeQWhLZJpvOUeWvdLTIo68ZTap5zHX6gjf6kSEu920OwOd1UkOXrLQ6huKThQbZ8SYSzwwgmQWmTNZsA@1UVVzI@lRttHZlAdkxm2bBFKAD1D4JqeMjMDgfzJJPBFwyYVb8LjZlNvMsIXwAiD68Z8cRUZMdAh0WCTlCWTu5wlgDyNuKXupGTlUIvf6uzCYErDnCDpLoagqzaaTx4MORtRBmbuHvTOGLhsD27PUL6kdMiLGC2dHThVcsD3mgV9XMkGLq07d5YKMhJQQZYDzSrGMqF@ddNwNmC87g6hLvYBaCHBEnv9yyRcAysILj6jAWmAhvCTmFWNESjY/Q3wmQ9/NOE15EsVdMsCQTTTtCmhqVSC8rPB3AHOQaOwUZiACSuJ@iilg0kgexiZJfubxJU/JEKYTXauINDSJcgsFRViLo0dVo0fl0Rmfy2JvB7ELVk5gjFM3JVFuCkYydqvlHjQVt0x61K1WyiA24QkupQGrFFm1FJ0qwyfp0U1pKW9BUjZzJ3Ja7bBRW5Fu7GrQ2FmwyEzN0Ia1UlFTwZ1gcCc26IN0iiG/m7Iahdy2oodFfpI5Xj4nwdU5WU8ghAjHwSWivFRj9C8s0mCcpD/a5nytvIYjv8QyCZe8bZSNs2QuKsiAWnxc@BW5/JRYtgKeqzEXMCjhWz8k6Ymj1PAWfDAdPJ2DBzqE@hPQiSshk/RU@oorMmSXm96cjMnuGCi51GF75VaT7KIC91qtMwGaxTwTTDUKJz0Sgh@OrS0TlQ5cqIX@M94yN7FrYIsZscTMJSKUXijj7sGWGShgLY45KjI1DKU9w3Ao5ChGrMQIAYiTSYNj5cXg0lV97ZP95v35VHy8@BSnyZEXkgN0p8i/0fsc6mXHZ50tcVxyBBhUb/U7ct0MvzTH2FWen2nJuqo/zztC6iRZUucVZC@KXhr3ySXGcdZV9rXSg3WiwuYuzIe9fPqxYjIMKrw4o7VsajQoO3NpUmzrk9vWIPdIn9wjDXKP9ck91iD3RJ/cEw1yT/XJPdUg960@uW81yD3TJ/dMg9xzfXLPNci90Cf3QoOc3cCNdabFzw3o6XgeazAvdIz7usHE0JloVoOZoWPeVw18WWduTBu4i443v2niLzoO81MjgjoUP67tkPVXzPQZZga6xJNHmMr0dSL2P8jm0L0Gmw0dNj6yUcvdiTpVq@JDFytwdSqmwOh0wtyTY66pjvA6ox6hgLLaQksk5N1WecFWAkSrPWRKsNutFbz9R3ulY@TP1M78kNXrsq3ha@rcoiad2di@6K4ilMuoNoZku0IjRxT3JR7m8yJzULkU@wb6wb5l3bIDVLnsBtXw0z7iOw1HeNwr7wFkXwfkNwjyKLQl9@z5PYD8RgfkVhRYJJuA91j8kgdVW6XbB7u1pYP2K6VSYYW2uAeMX@lAfI8QX195wl0WqG/Z6lpmD9QE@su/DsIyc7y92RzDxi/@GgCDDu12q4L0AZczDpvZBlHpXwT99vjsRjH/q6Our1U8fPvqHuz5tQ6@vxHf8ck9wPtbB56B8H67F3zvAV@F951WbuJLwCkC99SpqVicRO6vTBWyp8BAQEM9o0ouB/pcRjpc9hWX5IBdT5j8CbCeNAfVfA4a8NGSp4d84tPYJYcyOQ7JsW0t4R0kbIWezU11@gqiiPEKDp8beeh1epZQf5dHvbg80QWe3Kfookr60xsYUJLGQWkccZlXP86PiEgly@gq47OMkWBTJDTwHaX4CopWNynxwWc9vqY618bn1eiPuKrAIqj2C0eErtTdwbmLHdygFw1dsYfTttHN2OldjZ0ekB5W@8I1/eF7FSyj2pn4qnvQ3370TNfv0kKbDuwzi@cKXQ0AX6Rr3OKWrDZoV5xlxPdoOiy/RJbBjHrK0HImCJfMCYhwrx3Mbz3ijzTkO1E2FTJZpOTUZ@xuZTRvXRHmdVRWeZ9T0uMp6tEULq6bbqpMcJeIcHD3foJzLJAo0gb@oVozbFIUY7kDxNfAyKbd3vwguKvYud1FIEsPvvBCennQMzHMQTDJhL7MlV48uv5Er4lyELyGOnisDkj7JAEinGPIj2Nfp191Pp4TqheH6NxVeE6u5WIBlGjw3pA8eR6XF@Lv3SF5@mz5uNyJI7A4V0jwOloNB9D1ch9m5V5UNUUa6GzcmdyDvNgvPltqgNyqF/tKpb8ciPhWfcq@0u9KtH/L0tZJrHUW9RKXELn84vZPK0m6ummIKt6IZnOzk3QIBpZOnPklxjlZijMbU66imHJViimtOjfI16nctJgVZwKHW8cajibUUYuqxsAy3P3Tl4eHcc1andctShFKNaBLyxEKopSLRysvI/CjunTMaf4aqNuDaW0N220NSx8vFVVnEty/tOnkayK0mxc6jqAP18BZ4zYQ8@1yMR@qcSsMuxC4Yj6/FK70hU1@sMWsXiG7qJCfWRBAHk1v@wYE1bdLGwWu7WpKTEfVTcuN9lAX/wfzqILku1HH3sNVx1Bd6fwVglvfgSKGwwerifbvbdDEAZMzxtyHsLVEfWF2aeJ/D9eB/ocOdMZ8h@PGrHUzQRFfvWFXXOrklusIAOKhpepbqU0@hI5XE9iV1lGvg1p9lEsQahF9QEQ/AgrM5maQWAdNahzy9TP13H5MueG7Yc3Y9fPsNjTYnSO7X7Hsta9qZqNi4tXqjnLeLzDpXbnByu2U@tsXNRZaJlUqVLYAuraYtlLai4K0sCTflqx7typqv1A6s34YVfKrVs9n6qAjSN/Hw3e@4jKjckl7dc0xTuayAOtn@BIAl5ByjclsylzYOgtg7CtvlRx0BWzHsCu2auqOm9UxRe@dldAcI2t1N6/Oa7ls6QfJUnFTDK5QAbB@pK4mkrfSim@jaYUWdmUyT5Kf2HwkYEJjDYvvh54svCFSjpLxwNfqD4RDNGRBnPVT4bDobb4ZcyWZ@cKd9PCEVczAOAQ4iTzcKEVde31ycnyyQ6qGF@40owHp@6qbEAYdKg0AVzzczogQ1dcfOnjLh/6i8vdW04R86ZXoZ57o0eHShXqxLaNLdief/gM) <sup>I'm using TIO for this one instead of the JS-based online interpreter cause Python numbers. I recommend running it locally.</sup>

### Explanation

```
lH^       - Push 10^100
   [   ]  - While not zero:
    ho{   -   Print codepoint 97 (a) and decrement the counter
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 72 bytes

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.*;fun main()=repeat(2.0.pow(3).toInt()){_->println()}
```

### Ungolfed

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.*;

fun main() =
  repeat(2.0.pow(3).toInt()) { _ -> println() }
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Mbigint`, 32 bytes

```perl
$i=0;say while 10**100>($i=$i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l09bAujixUqE8IzMnVcHQQEvL0MDATgMorpKpbaj5//@//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYGQDopMz0zrwQA)

Perl's `bigint` module allows for integers to be of arbitrary size.  It also overloads all of the math operators so that literal integers become `bigint`s.  Therefore, this satisfies the constraints of the challenge: it outputs one googol newlines, it does not exceed a reasonable amount of memory as it does not actually store a googol entries of any sort, and it will stop when `$i` reaches 1 googol.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, 35 bytes

BigInts ftw

```js
i=10n**100n;while(i--)console.log()
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 30 bytes

```julia
for i=1:big(10)^100 show(1)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/Py2/SCHT1tAqKTNdw9BAM87QwEChOCO/XMNQMzUv5f9/AA)

with `BigInt`s, no problem calculating \$10^{100}\$

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 72 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4764/98541)

```
102→dim(ʟA
Repeat ʟA(102
Disp 1
10→ʟA(1
For I,1,101
If 9<ʟA(I
1+ʟA(I+1→ʟA(I+1
End
ʟA not(ʟA>9→A
End
```

**Explanation:**

The list `ʟA` stores a base-10 101-digit number (from indices 2 to 102). `10` is put in `ʟA(1)` so that `ʟA(2)`, the last digit of the number, is incremented. We search all `10`s in the number to increment the next digit, and then remove them all with the line `ʟA*not(ʟA>9)→A`. We print a `1` each step, and stop when there is a non-zero in `ʟA(102)`, meaning we reached \$10^{100}\$

<sub>*there is a shorter TI-Basic answer but it won't work due to the limited precision of big numbers (which are floats)*</sub>

[TI-83 online emulator](https://www.cemetech.net/projects/jstified/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 bytes

```
2ᴇᴇɬ*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f6OGWdiA6uUbr//9oQx0FIzACMkx0FCzADKWM1JycfKVYAA)

```
2ᴇᴇ     pushes 10^100
   ɬ*   pushes "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", and repeats it a
        total of 10^100 times; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 14 bytes

```
:n;10..*?{1p}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/3yrP2tBAT0/LvtqwoFbr/38A)

## Explanation

```
:n;10..*?{1p}*

:n;            # redefine (n)ewline as nothing (supresses the newline in 'p')
   10..*?    * # 10^100 times..
         {1p}  # print 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 9 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 7.41 bytes

```
10aS^{1ZL
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYrDQ0Sg-OqDaN8IHyoMEwaAA) Prints a googol `1`s.

##### Factoid

The `10aS` can be replaced with any of the following:

- `10Z2`
- `aAaS`
- `aAZ2`
- `Z1aS`
- `Z1Z2`

##### Explanation

Just multiplying a googol with a string won't work because of memory limits: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYrDA0Sg-PUE7UgXKgoTBYA)

So, we have to print each character separately:

```python
10         # Push 10, or
aA         # Push 10, or
Z1         # Push 10

  aS       # Push 100, or
  Z2       # Push 100

    ^      # Push 10 ** 100

     {     # Loop that many times:

      1ZL  #  Print 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 9 bytes

`10ä²^Må1£`

prints googol `1`s

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=MTDksl5NMaM=)

*The online interpreter will stop after the first 10000 characters of the program output*

### Explantion

```
10ä²^Må1£
10        ; literal 10
  ä       ; duplicate
   ²      ; square -> 100
    ^     ; power: gives 10^100
     Må   ; for all elements of the 1-based range, discarding the index
       1£ ; print one
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 9 bytes

```
echo~!!6x
```

[Attempt (smaller version of) This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8GCpaUlaboWK1KTM_LrFE0qIFyoKEwWAA)

Mildly surprised that no one has thought of using factorial here so far. Googol divides 405!, so n! copies of a string where n ≥ 405 is a googol copies of some much longer string. (For the sake of a 404 joke, googol does not divide 404!.)

`!!6x` evaluates to 720!, and then `echo~` prints the value of 720! followed by newline 720! times. `echo` is defined to be `0 0 $ 1!:2&2`, so `echo~ x` evaluates like this:

```
echo~ x
x echo x
x (0 0 $ 1!:2&2) x
0 0 $ x 1!:2&2 x
0 0 $ (iterate 1!:2&2 x times on x)
```

`1!:2&2` prints its argument with newline and returns it unchanged, so `echo~ x` prints x plus newline x times.

Answer (score 0):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 40 bytes (7×13=91 codels)

```
tliumliusabdNt?fqasjfceqtMtL?E?Ukl?_ti ?
```

[Try Piet online! (10 instead of googol)](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJyrVkrOT0lVsoqONtAx0zE00DHVMTQEsSwwUawOUBGIZaxjomOIXQ1MGVDWEj8CKgMpNydSoSkx6iwRLsenzADkURAHr7pYHaXi1AIlKyVdXV0lHaWczFwg28gABIDc1OJkJau0xJziVB2lzLyC0hKgpFItABrCSFI)

[image]

The horizontal path pushes a googol, and then the vertical loop prints `3` that many times.

- A1 .. A6: `3 dup * 1 +` push 10
- A6 .. A13 .. B13 .. B5: `dup * dup * dup dup * dup * dup * dup dup * * *` push the 100th power of that
- B5 .. B3: `1 CC+` set up the IP so that when it enters the size-3 block again, it bounces off on the right side
- C1 .. C2 .. G2 .. G1 .. F1: `3 outN 1 - dup ! DP+` print 3, decrement the counter, test if it is zero and turn right to exit (F4 .. G4)

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), <strike>22</strike> 20 bytes

```
'cka'bk*1#;_@#:-1.0;
```

#### Explanation

```
# Construct googol
'c                   Push 99
  ka                 Iterate "push 10" 99 times, then pushes it again
    'b               Push 98
      k*             Iterate "multiply" 98 times, then once more (10^100)
        1#           Push 1, jump into print loop with 1 and googol as top two of stack
# Print loop (goes RTL after first encountering _ with 1 on the stack)
          ;        ; 
                 .0  Prints 0
               -1    Decrement iterator
           _@#:      Exit if iterator is 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XT85OVE/K1jJUto53ULbSNdQzsP7/HwA)

### [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/Funge-98/) (theoretical), 13 bytes

```
'cka'bk*1-k.@
```

#### Explanation

```
'cka'bk*       Construct googol as above
        1-     Subtract 1 (TOS is 10^100 - 1)
          k.@  Iterate "print TOS" (0) 10^100 - 1 times, then once more, then exit.
```

Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for PyFunge because the number is too big to iterate with, and I think the number is just too big to store at all for FBBI.